# Solution wihout using Temp variable

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with online tests to improve my coding logic and I had a test where I needed to create a sample of a chessboard, where basically the input would be rows and columns of the chessboard, and then generate the output that was asked, but I'm not quite happy with my solution, I wonder if it is possible having the same output without having a temp variable, for example store the input values in a array and using some array functions that keeps looping inside giving me different values in the for loops. Here is my code:

```
/*
Sample output:
0101010
1010101
0101010
1010101
*/
function chess(m, n) { //7,4
    var zero = 0;
    var um = 1;
    var temp = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (var r = 0; r < m; r++) {

            if (temp === 1) {
                document.write(um);
                temp = 0;
            }
            else {
                document.write(zero);
                temp = 1;
            }
        }
        document.write("<br>");
    }
}
chess(7, 4);
```

Comment: That's a pretty simple pattern. All you need is `(i + j) % 2 == 0 ? '0': '1'`. In any case, this is not a good question for SO, so don't be surprised when it's closed in a few minutes. Try CodeReview next time :)

Comment: @Luaan `(i+j)%2` will do fine. You do not need ternary operator.

Comment: just for fun, try writing it with no vars (other than m or n)

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
function chess(m,n){ //7,4
var zero = 0;
var um = 1;
var temp = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){

        for(var r = 0; r < m; r++){

            if((i+r)%2 === 1){
                document.write(um); 
            }else{
                document.write(zero);
           }                       
        }
        document.write("<br>");     
    }
}
chess(7,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly compute and print. You do not need to store it in any variable.

```js
function chess(m,n){ //7,4
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(var r = 0; r < m; r++){
            document.write((i+r)%2);
        }
        document.write("<br>");     
    }
}
chess(7,4);
```